# How to create non .NET core web API?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

We need to create a web API project from Visual Studio 2017, however, it seems the only option is to create .NET Core version of it. Any idea on how to create traditional web API?

I tried going through create project scenarios, but the web api option is not available.

Here is the screnshot:
[image]

Comment: Quite the opposite, the project templates are there. There is no `traditional web API` anyway.

Comment: Unable to find them. Please suggest.

Comment: [Check the docs?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) The [Get Started with ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) page shows how to create a legacy Web API project step by step

Comment: The option is visible in the screenshot you posted. It's the third from the bottom. Why do you want a legacy Web API project though? It's not just that the technology is old and lacking features, the documentation and tutorials are old and won't appear in searches.

Comment: It as some learning curve and we don't have time for that. It's internal api and used for internal app. Can you please post your previous comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 - GoTo to Visual Studio Installer -> 'Select your Version' -> Click 'Modify'

Ref - https://www.screencast.com/t/3AAGkmSPG4S

[image: Step 1]

Step 2 - Under Individual Components Tab ->  Check required  development tools as your wish and modify

Ref - https://www.screencast.com/t/ZJAe4HUc90V

[image: step 2]

Step 3 - Create a new application as shown in in figure -> select WebAPI on next step

Ref - https://www.screencast.com/t/IIMsnPcWUxu
[image: step 3]

[image: final]